# DevOps AreaPath changes

Tags: devops

I moved several features and stories to a new area path and the system is requesting I go in and save each one separately, is there a way to group the SAVE change? I have over 5K to move

I can go in and save each one without an issue, but I am looking for an automated way to make the area path change, and then save without having to go into each feature and story to save

Comment: Bulk edit? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops